# Giving a relative path, so that the sound works as I run the jar file on any machine

Tags: java

In the `utility` package as shown in the snapshot, there is a class `Constants`. In the same directory as of `utility` there is a `folder` called `sounds`, also shown in the snapshot. Till now I have been giving the complete path of the `.wav` files.

*`Like W:/UnderTest/Blaah/Blaaaaah/Foo/sounds/file.wav`*

How should I give the path, so that when I make a `.jar` file of it, the sound still works. I tried this :

```
../sounds/Player_1.wav
```

but it doesn't work and I get `java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\sounds\Player_1.wav (The system cannot find the path specified)`

[image]

Comment: Have you try this: "/sounds/Player_1.wav" ?

Answer (score 1):

try this....

```
URL url = Constants.class.getResource("/sounds/file.wav");
```

the url in which now gets the path of your file....

Comment: It gets me this : `file:/W:/UnderTest/NetbeansCurrent/tic-tac-toe/build/classes/sounds/Player_1.wav`

Comment: Is this the only way ? I will have to edit the string to remove `file:/`

Comment: URL url = pdftopng.class.getResource("/sounds/file.wav");
String pth=url.getPath().substring(1);
System.out.println(pth);

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this it's best to load the resource relative to the root classpath:

```
URL soundURL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
        .getResource("/sounds/file.wav");
```

You can also get the resource as a stream:

```
InputStream soundURLStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream("/sounds/file.wav");
```

The main difference between this and `Class.getResource` is that `Class.getResource` assumes that the supplied path is relative to ***its*** location in the class hierarchy. So given the relative path "/sounds/file.wav", calling `getResource` from a class `utility.Constants`, would attempt to resolve the `file.wav` resource from package `utility.sounds`. Whereas using the class loader and the same relative path, the resource would be resolved from `sounds`. A subtle but important difference.

Comment: How is it different from @NidhishKrishnan answer ? I mean are they both safe ?

Comment: Hey @saplingPro, see edit to my answer for brief explanation of the difference.